# Using awk to only grab first instance of a regex

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a bunch of `.txt` files in a directory which have information regarding dipole moment. This is how it looks like:

```
Dipole Moment: [D]
     X:     1.2808      Y:     0.2908      Z:     1.0187     Total:     1.6622
lorem ipsum
text 
that is 
not 
relevant 
Dipole Moment: [D]
     X:     1.2808      Y:     0.2908      Z:     1.0187     Total:     1.6622
more text
```

I want to extract the total dipole moment from these files. I am running the following script:

```
awk '/Dipole Moment: \[D\]/{found=1;next} found{print $NF;found=""}' *.txt > dipole_bma.txt
```

This script prints out 1.6622 twice. And every other `Total` dipole moment in each file twice. I see that it prints it out twice because the regex appears twice in the file.

My question is, how do I print total dipole moment only once from each file?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I answered this question for the OP earlier today at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65793414/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`nextfile` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html):

```
awk '/Dipole Moment: \[D\]/{found=1;next} found{print $NF;nextfile;}' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @pLumo. However, it doesn't seem to work... I am getting blank lines after the first output...

Comment: with your example it works for me ... do you have some non-unix line endings?

Comment: Technically, the files I am using are .out files, so the final *.txt becomes *.out. I dont know how that could make a difference...

Comment: no, the extension does not make any difference

Comment: @megamence sounds you don't have GNU `awk` that supports `nextfile`; instead use another second flag for that like `awk 'FNR==1 {once=0; }; /Dipole Moment: \[D\]/ { found=1; next}; found && !once{ print $NF; found=0; once=1; }' file*`, but however it still continue reading whole file while it only print once.

Comment: that link says that `nextfile` is  Posix since 2012 ...

Comment: @pLumo please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588906/72456

Answer (score 0):

Gnu sed can do as follows:

```
sed -ns '
  /^Dipole Moment: \[D]/!d
  $!N;/\n/s/.* //p;:n;n;bn
' ./*.txt
```

- `-s` option (nonPosix) to treat files as separate streams.
- `-n` will inhibit default print of the pattern space prior to fetching the next record.
- After the dipole moment line we stick the next line to the patter space.
- Remove till the last space (assuming no trailing whitespace) this prints the last field, i.e., the value of dipole moment.
- then we skid to the end of current file. The whole process repeats for the next file.